# Block drivers signed by specific code signing certificate

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, code-signing

I have quite an unusual problem. I like to have everything on my PC containerized and therefore I run type 1 hypervisor like KVM (Proxmox) or VMware ESXi on my computers. The issue I am trying to solve is that certain anti-cheat software just straight up bans me without any warning when it detects that it's running in a VM. I have learned my lesson to not play anything with intrusive anti-cheat, but I am still a bit worried that I could get banned by accident in some random game and get a game ban on my old Steam profile.

What I would like to do is to simply block all drivers with a certain code signing certificate (let's say EAC or BE) so that their driver would not load and the games would just throw an error on start.

Currently, I am just running my VMs with kernel debug option turned on so the ACs fail to initialize, but I feel like there has to be a way to just block certain drivers by their certificate since for example Windows Defender has a driver blacklist when running with HVCI enabled (maybe it can be altered?)

Is it somehow possible or would it require too many system hacks to archive? I wasn't really able to find anything about blocking certain drivers apart from disabling a device in the device manager (which in this case is useless).

Comment: Windows keeps a list of revoked certificates (see "Untrusted Certificates" `certmgr.msc` ). It contains the active certificate revocation lists. Unfortunately I don't know how to add custom revocation lists or certificates there.

Comment: @Robert Thank you! That was exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: This does not really fit the original question, but if anyone in the future stumbles upon this, better way of blocking the driver would be to use driver block rules (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/microsoft-recommended-driver-block-rules) instead of the certificate block.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway as it was mentioned in the comments, there is a list of untrusted certificates in the certmgr utility.

Going into the file properties -> certificate details -> view certificate -> install certificate, I was able to select "Untrusted Certificates" as the destination.

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]
[image: screen3]